# Php multiple browser detect and redirect

Tags: php, browser, redirect

How do I redirect firefox users to one landing page, chrome users to second, and everybody else is not redirected ?

I GOT it to work for chrome but how do I set a firefox condition to this code?

```
<?php
if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) )
{
  $t_bIsChrome = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome');
  if ( $t_bIsChrome !== false)
  {
    header("Location: redirect.php");
    exit;
  }
} 
?>
```

Anyone know?

Comment: Please, please don't sniff browsers...

Comment: Like @Blender said, you should never ever do that, unless maybe for IE6. Instead, use feature detection.

Answer (score 2):

While I whole-heartedly agree with @Blender's comment above, if you really must do this, [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) is the way.